# Nook HD+ Keyboard Issue

Tags: nook

Currently I am having massive amounts of problems with my Nook.

It's a NOOK HD plus BNTV600 I had received from my mother to try and fix. She says that while downloading a new update it had shut down and just wouldn't work afterword. Then tried factory resetting it which only lead to more problems.

The biggest problems currently are the keyboard and the constant crashing.
The problem with the Keyboard is that there is no keyboard. The monitors keyboard never shows up to type in the Wi-Fi password or to find a network which disallows me to even get past the starting settings of the Nook.

The other problem is the constant crashing, as I mentioned I can't get past the start up after factory resetting it. Well I originally thought it is just a problem with the hardware and it just taking a while to boot up and load the keyboard. Well, after a while it will just stop responding. It will bring up a notification telling me that the application is not responding and if I would like to wait for it to respond. If I hit wait, it will just continue to freeze up and an every 15 seconds it will bring the prompt again until it inevitably freezes and crashes.

I did when selecting either American English or British English. If I connect it to my PC I can get into the settings, however going to general crashes it instantly. And if I am on the settings screen long enough it will also crash.

Any ideas on how to fix this? Factory resetting it again doesn't work. I am thinking of unplugging the battery or getting a new battery entirely. But I am not sure if that would fix the problem.